# Python-class as a service

Tags: python, architecture

What is the good design of a class that will be treated like a service: it initializes from big data on disk and then responds the requests from another module?

Can it be just class with static data? The data is loaded from disk by calling Init function and after that one can make requests for the class.

Could you please criticize this solution? Would you suggest something better?

Comment: It would be easier to comment on your idea if you sketch it out with a few lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

From your description I understand that you're suggesting reading all the data from disk into members of a class instance or similar (I wouldn't use module globals if that's what you're planning) and then responding to requests using that data - have I understood you correctly?

This approach will work fine as long as you have enough memory on the system - since I don't know how big your data is, I can't comment on whether that's realistic. However, you're imposing scalability limitations on your code, so if the data ever gets bigger then you risk having your code run very slowly or cause crashes. Different platforms respond slightly differently to memory exhaustion, but the results are almost invariably ungraceful.

Where possible it might be better to read the data from disk on demand, possibly with some in-memory caching if appropriate. I would suggest putting your data into a structured format if you can, something like [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) is a fairly simple way of creating structured file data. You can then write methods which perform SQL queries to recover data from the file as you need it.

If you need to then get better performance by caching common results in memory, you can use something like Python 3's [LRU cache](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator around all the functions you want to cache. This does assume that the results of the function depend only on its arguments. If you're using Python 2.x then you can find [implementations for that too](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498245-lru-and-lfu-cache-decorators/), although not in the standard library.

If your results depend on class members as well as function arguments, you'll probably need to do some extra work, either by writing your own caching layer or by using the above solutions and manually clearing the cache whenever the appropriate class members change. I can't give you specifics without knowing a lot more about your problem, but hopefully that covers the issues involved.

Does that answer your question, or have I missed the point? Please provide clarification if you need a different answer.

**EDIT**

After your comment below, I thought I'd add a bit more clarification.

Firstly I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "static" data - Python doesn't really have this concept in the same way that something like C/C++ or Java do. You can have *class attributes* which are stored in the class object and available to the instances as if they were regular attributes:

```
class MyClass(object):

    class_attribute = 123

    def method(self):
        print "Class attribute value: %d" % (self.class_attribute,)
```

... But in this case I don't think that's a good idea. Perhaps by "static" you just mean a bunch of data stored as attributes of a class instance, and if so that seems a perfectly sensible option for what you describe.

So your class would end up with an `__init__()` method which would probably take something like a filename as a parameter (even if the file where you store your data is fixed right now it might not be in the future, plus it might be useful to use a different one for unit tests). This method would then cause the data to be loaded and stored as instance attributes. I would suggest delegating the actual loading to another method, so you can reload the data without having to construct a new instance.

To take a simple example, if your class was storing lines from a file then you might have:

```
class FileLines(object):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.lines = []
        self.load_file(filename)

    def load_file(self, filename):
        with open(filename, "r") as fd:
            self.lines = [i.rstrip() for i in fd]
```

(I realise that setting `lines` in `__init__()` isn't strictly required because it's reset in `load_file()`, but I think it's good practice to initialise all attributes in `__init__()`).

This is clearly a pretty pointless class, but you get the idea - read the data from `__init__()` and then make it available. Incidentally I quite intentionally didn't add a "getter" method for the `lines` attribute - in Python it's perfectly acceptable to access attributes directly, there's no need for the "getter" and "setter" methods you often see in C/C++ and Java. This is because you can use [properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) in Python to replace simple attributes with methods later if you need to implement more complex functionality. So, you can have the simplicity of basic attributes now with flexibility for later as well.

Also, presuming your data has structure you should give some thought to how you store it. Dictionaries, lists and sets are all very powerful in Python, but if your data has named fields then consider using [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or a custom class to represent it. This makes it more convenient (and hence less error-prone) for users of the class to access it. Ideally I would suggest trying to keep the in-memory representation of the object in one class and have the code to parse the on-disk representation somewhere else which produces instances of the in-memory version. Keeping the representations separate in this way will allow you to insulate users of your class from changes in the on-disk representation.

Hopefully that's been of some help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, you understood me correctly. It seem that I can read all the data into memory, the big data itself is not a problem here. That question is more about the architecture of the class. Should it contain static data? Should it have Init method?